# How to make a dynamic select column on MySQL for my search

Tags: php, mysql

Example $_GET on my search form.

- `$_GET['s']` = keyword
- `$_GET['c']` = category
- `$_GET['r']` = region
- `$_GET['t']` = type

Example if statement :

```
if(isset($s)) {
  $s = "title LIKE '%{$keyword}%";
}

if(isset($c)) {
  $c = " AND category='{$category}'";
}

if(isset($r)) {
  $r = " AND region='{$region}'";
}

if(isset($t)) {
  $t = " AND type='{$type}'";
}
```

Then MySQL query :

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE $s.$c.$r.t AND status='1'";
```

Question :

How to make my `$select` can be dynamic? Current way is only worked if all input is not empty. Other than that give me syntax error. :P

Let me know..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create multiple variables, you can do something like this:

```
$s = '';

if(isset($s)) {
  $s .= " AND title='%$keyword%'";
}

if(isset($c)) {
  $s .= " AND category='{$category}'";
}

if(isset($r)) {
  $s .= " AND region='{$region}'";
}

if(isset($t)) {
  $s .= " AND type='{$type}'";
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE status='1' $s";
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like that?

```
$conditions = array("status='1'");
if(isset($s)) {
  $conditions []= "title LIKE '%{$keyword}%'";
}
if(isset($c)) {
  $conditions []= "category='{$category}'";
}
if(isset($r)) {
  $conditions []= "region='{$region}'";
}
if(isset($t)) {
  $conditions []= "type='{$type}'";
}
$select = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $conditions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it works as is now even if all the inputs are not empty?

Change your query to as follows AND add a space at the end of each criteria:

```
if(isset($s)) 
{   
    $s = " AND title LIKE '%$keyword%' "; //Changed the = to LIKE
}  
if(isset($c)) 
{   
    $c = " AND category='{$category}' "; 
}  
if(isset($r)) 
{   
    $r = " AND region='{$region}' "; 
}  
if(isset($t)) 
{   
    $t = " AND type='{$type}' "; 
}

$select = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE status='1' $s.$c.$r.t";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$sArr = array("status='1'");

if(isset($s)) {
  $sArr[] = "title LIKE '%{$keyword}%";
}

if(isset($c)) {
  $sArr[] = "category='{$category}'";
}

if(isset($r)) {
  $sArr[] = "region='{$region}'";
}

if(isset($t)) {
  $sArr[] = "type='{$type}'";
}

$where = "WHERE " . join(' AND ', $sArr);
$select = "SELECT * FROM ads " . $where;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change inialization  to $s = ' 1=1 ';
 to fix the problem.

Hope this helps.